# Encontrar máximos en un arreglo unidimensional en python

Tags: python, scipy

Soy nuevo en python y tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un fichero `.txt` que ya he logrado cargar y guardar en un arreglo. Luego he buscado los máximos en el arreglo y los he graficado, pero el criterio de búsqueda es muy pobre y me encuentra demasiados máximos, he tratado de usar

```
 signal.find_peaks_cwt(x, np.arange())
```

pero no tengo idea de como implementarlo con lo que ya tengo adelantado. Aquí les va el código que he implementado:

```
import numpy
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Setup and plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

with open ("NC.txt", "r") as input_file:
   data = numpy.loadtxt('NC.txt')

y = np.array(data)
x = np.linspace(1, 2048, y.size)
ax[0].plot(x,y)

#get peaks
peaks_indx = argrelextrema(y, np.greater)[0]
peaks = y[peaks_indx]
ax[0].plot(x[peaks_indx],y[peaks_indx],'o')

#Get maxpeak
maxpeak = 0.
for p in peaks_indx:
    print(p)
    if y[p] > maxpeak:
        maxpeak = y[p]
        maxpeak_indx = p

#Get mask of data around maxpeak to plot
mincutoff = 0.
indx_to_plot = np.zeros(y.size, dtype=bool)
for i in range(maxpeak_indx):
    if y[maxpeak_indx-i] > mincutoff:
        indx_to_plot[maxpeak_indx-i] = True
    else:
        indx_to_plot[maxpeak_indx-i] = True
        break

for i in range(y.size-maxpeak_indx):
    if y[maxpeak_indx+i] > mincutoff:
        indx_to_plot[maxpeak_indx+i] = True
    else:
        indx_to_plot[maxpeak_indx+i] = True
        break
ax[1].plot(x[indx_to_plot],y[indx_to_plot])
plt.show()
```

Si alguien pudiera darme una idea de como implementar el

```
 signal.find_peaks_cwt(x, np.arange())
```

y luego plotear los datos resaltando los máximos como lo hace este código.

El `NC.txt` es simplemente un fichero con 2048 números y esta en

http://pastebin.com/k29eSjGA

Estoy usando Python34.

Por favor cualquier sugerencia seria de gran ayuda!!!!

Comment: Hola Ricardo, si te es posible estaría bien que pasaras el fichero NC.txt (usa pastebin o cualquier otro medio). Lo digo porque una de las cosas importantes a la hora de calcular los picos es ver el nivel de ruido que tienen los datos e ir ajustando según este.  Para probar el código y modificarlo es de gran ayuda contar con los datos originales que usas (o al menos una muestra significativa de ellos).

Comment: Define un poco mejor qué es guardar los máximos en tu contexto. Si no es imposible poder darte una respuesta. Por otra parte, como comenta @FJSevilla, estaría bien que pusieras una muestra del fichero de texto que estás usando para poder entender mejor el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Varias cosas:

Para replicar `signal.find_peaks_cwt` tienes que convolucionar los datos a una wavelet. Lee https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_wavelet_transform De ahí la "_cwt" final del nombre de la función. Es decir, primero convierte los datos a una función y de esa obtiene los máximos.

De tu ejemplo no entiendo qué quieres hacer con el segundo gráfico.

En tu código estás usando `scipy.signal.argrelextrema` y eso funciona. Te recomiendo que aumentes el tamaño del gráfico y los apiles porque no estás viendo nada. Por ejemplo a `plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(20, 10))`

Creo que además estás ignorando el parámetro opcional `order` en `scipy.signal.argrelextrema`. Por omisión es 1 y ese no es un valor muy útil la verdad. Si le pasas 20 el primer gráfico *estirado* queda así:

[image: graficado de scipy.signal.argrelextrema]